# Counting errors and continue in a loop

Tags: python

I have some python code which is sending several hundred API requests at a time, there can occasionally be `HttpError` failures with formatting in the individual requests, but I do not want this to stop the whole process.

To enable this I added an exception to my if statement:

```
def update_conversions(service):

  for req in request_bodies:
    try:
      request = service.conversion().update(body=req)
    except Exception:
      pass
```

I would like to update this code to get viability of the number or requests that failed, while still continuing the loop, how could I update my code to assign a count of http errors to a variable?

Comment: Add a counter and increment it in `except`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
def update_conversions(service):
  total_failed_requests = 0

  for req in request_bodies:
    try:
      request = service.conversion().update(body=req)
    except Exception:
      total_failed_requests += 1
      print(f"A request has failed, total: {total_failed_requests}")
```

Comment: Thank you, do I still need the `pass` in place?

Comment: `pass` means `do nothing`. Since we are executing other instructions in the `except` statement, there is no need of `pass` anymore